# Struts 2 : Is it possible to get html content in interceptor?

Tags: struts2, interceptor

I'd like to know if it is possible to get html content send to browser in interceptor ?
My aim is to get one div content and convert it in pdf.
Thanks

Comment: You want to send the content of a div, and convert it to a pdf? There is the jasper plugin... A report which only prints a string should be pretty easy. I think, Jasper understands html so it should be able to handle basic formatting if required although I've not tried to render content formatted with html. You will need JS (jquery is a good bet) to get the content of the div and then send it to the action as a string.

Comment: @Umesh Awasthi Could you explain i did not understand your comment.

Comment: [struts2-pdfstream](https://github.com/aleksandr-m/struts2-pdfstream).

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about your question,and moreover if they are with respect to some specific actions i do not favor the approach to handle such use-case in interceptors,since in general interceptors are more towards cross-cutting concern and they are applied to whole stack you have configured rather than for some particular action.

Additionally the data will not be thread safe if its specific to action, being said that you can still have access to the parameters send to your action class from UI

```
Map parameters = ActionContext.getContext().getParameters();
```

The request parameters are available on the ActionContext instance, which is made available via ThreadLocal.

You can create your own interceptor and can get access to the parameters as follow

```
actionInvocation.getInvocationContext().getParameters();
```

above line will give you all request parameters from jsp page on which you have called any
action.

Hope that will help you.